# List exceeds threshold. query large lists

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, list-view-threshold, large-lists

I have a list that exceeds the 5000 threshold. total is 16013. Is it possible to query lists of this size. I can get all of contents with no query in batch using

```
query..ListItemCollectionPosition
```

But can I query just folders and then files, in the test I am running I have a folder that contains 16000 files and then a single folder. Can I query this list efficiently to find this folder. I've tried this:

```
query.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' /><Value Type='ContentTypeId'>0x0120</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query><RowLimit>" + FileFoldeBatchSize + "</RowLimit></View>";
```

then when I want to query for files this :

```
query.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Lookup'>0</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>" + FileFoldeBatchSize + "</RowLimit></View>";
```

When trying to query for files, this will timeout with the following set:

```
clientContext.RequestTimeout = 1800000;
```

I've tried setting different row limits and still the same result

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, it seems like MS made an unannounced change related to this at some point in the last 2-4 weeks. You used to be able to prevent the threshold error by filtering based on indexed/built-in fields, (so long as the filtered results counted less than 5000) but that no longer seems to be the case.

That said, I have two suggestions that might work for you. The first is a generic solution that should work for both lists and libraries, while the second is specifically for libraries.

## List/Library Solution

*Since you already know about retrieving the list item in batches, this is more for other people looking for an answer to their threshold-related issue. The `FilesOnly` value in the `Scope` attribute might help your situation, though.*

I ran into an issue a few weeks back where one of my applications started hitting the threshold error after running fine for 2 years. After trying all sorts of modifications to the query, I finally ended up with the following:

```
    private static CamlQuery BuildFilesQuery(List spList, string queryFolder=null)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(queryFolder) && !spList.RootFolder.IsPropertyAvailable("ServerRelativeUrl")) {
            spList.Context.Load(spList.RootFolder,
                folder => folder.ServerRelativeUrl
            );
            spList.Context.ExecuteQuery();
            queryFolder = spList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
        }

        return new CamlQuery() {
            ViewXml = @"
                <View Scope='FilesOnly'>
                    <RowLimit>5000</RowLimit>
                </View>",
            FolderServerRelativeUrl = queryFolder
        };
    }

    public static IList<ListItem> LoadRecordsQuery(List spList, string queryFolder=null, CamlQuery spQuery=null, ListItemCollectionPosition position=null)
    {
        spQuery = spQuery ?? BuildQuery(spList, queryFolder);
        spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = position;
        ListItemCollection spItems = spList.GetItems(spQuery);
        spList.Context.Load(spItems, items => items.ListItemCollectionPosition);
        spList.Context.ExecuteQuery();

        List<ListItem> spItemsList = spItems.ToList();
        if(spItems.ListItemCollectionPosition != null) {
            spItemsList.AddRange(LoadRecordsQuery(spList, queryFolder, spQuery, spItems.ListItemCollectionPosition));
        }

        return spItemsList;
    }
```

To use this, you'd call: `LoadRecordsQuery(spList)` This should give you all of the files (or list items) in the root folder of your list/library. If you want to query the files in a subfolder instead, pass the folder's server-relative url to the `queryFolder` parameter. Unfortunately you'll have to do any sorting/filtering on the client side, as the threshold behavior has become inconsistent when `<Where>` and `<OrderBy>` clauses are used. (at least in my experience)

If I understood correctly, you already have a working solution for querying folders. If not, let me know and I'll edit this section.

## Library-Only Solution (WebDAV)

In your case, you're working on a document library, so you can use the WebDAV interface to list all files and folders in one request: (takes a little while, since it's such a big response)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Xml;

    using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities;

    namespace Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
    {
        internal static class FolderExtensions
        {
            #region Constants

            const int RequestTimeout = 60000;

            const string DAVNS = @"DAV:";
            const string UserAgent = @"Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601";
            const string PropFindBody = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?><propfind xmlns=""DAV:""><propname/></propfind>";

            #endregion

            #region DAV XML Parsing

            internal static XmlElement GetDAVElement(this XmlDocument self, string localName)
            {
                foreach(XmlElement element in self.GetElementsByTagName(localName, DAVNS))
                    return element;
                return null;
            }

            internal static XmlElement GetDAVElement(this XmlElement self, string localName)
            {
                foreach(XmlElement element in self.GetElementsByTagName(localName, DAVNS))
                    return element;
                return null;
            }

            internal static XmlNodeList GetDAVElements(this XmlDocument self, string localName)
            {
                return self.GetElementsByTagName(localName, DAVNS);
            }

            internal static XmlNodeList GetDAVElements(this XmlElement self, string localName)
            {
                return self.GetElementsByTagName(localName, DAVNS);
            }

            internal static IEnumerable<XmlElement> GetDAVResponses(this XmlDocument self)
            {
                foreach(XmlElement davElement in self.GetDAVElements(@"response")) {
                    yield return davElement;
                }
            }

            internal static string GetResponseHref(this XmlElement self)
            {
                // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
                return HttpUtility.UrlKeyValueDecode(self.GetDAVElement(@"href").InnerText.TrimEnd('/'));
            }

            internal static string GetRelativeResponseHref(this XmlElement self, string folderUrl)
            {
                return self.GetResponseHref().Substring(folderUrl.Length);
            }

            internal static bool IsFolderResponse(this XmlElement self)
            {
                return self.GetDAVElement("isFolder") != null;
            }

            #endregion

            #region Request Factories

            public static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(this ClientContext self, Uri requestUri, string requestMethod=WebRequestMethods.Http.Get)
            {
                // Grab a reference to the SPO credentials object.
                SharePointOnlineCredentials spoCreds = self.Credentials as SharePointOnlineCredentials;
                if(spoCreds == null) {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Request methods are only meant to be used with SharePoint Online.");
                }

                HttpWebRequest oRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
                oRequest.Pipelined = true;
                oRequest.UserAgent = UserAgent;
                oRequest.Method = requestMethod;
                oRequest.Timeout = RequestTimeout;
                // Wasteful. This re-processes the authentication logic every time to call it in order
                // to generate a new authentication cookie. This should definitely be cached somewhere in
                // your real code.
                oRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = spoCreds.GetAuthenticationCookie(requestUri, true);
                return oRequest;
            }

            public static HttpWebRequest CreateListRequest(this ClientContext clientContext, Uri folderUri, string requestBody = null)
            {
                char[] requestBodyChars = (requestBody ?? PropFindBody).ToCharArray();
                HttpWebRequest oRequest = CreateWebRequest(clientContext, folderUri, "PROPFIND");
                oRequest.Headers["Depth"] = "infinity,noroot";
                oRequest.Headers["Translate"] = "f";
                oRequest.ContentLength = requestBodyChars.LongLength;
                using(Stream requestStream = oRequest.GetRequestStream()) {
                    using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream)) {
                        writer.Write(requestBodyChars);
                        writer.Close();
                    }
                    requestStream.Close();
                }
                return oRequest;
            }

            #endregion

            #region List Request Processing

            public static IEnumerable<String> ListRecursively(this Folder oFolder, bool filesOnly=true)
            {
                // Grab references to the ClientContext and SPO Credentials objects.
                ClientContext clientContext = oFolder.Context as ClientContext;
                Debug.Assert(clientContext != null);
                SharePointOnlineCredentials spoCreds = clientContext.Credentials as SharePointOnlineCredentials;
                if(spoCreds == null) {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("ListFolder method is only meant to be used with SharePoint Online.");
                }

                // Load the ServerRelativeUrl property on our folder if necessary.
                if(!oFolder.IsPropertyAvailable("ServerRelativeUrl")) {
                    clientContext.Load(oFolder, folder => folder.ServerRelativeUrl);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }

                // Build the folder's absolute url.
                Uri folderUri = new Uri(
                    new Uri(clientContext.Url).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) +
                    oFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
                );

                // Read the request response as an xml document.
                XmlDocument responseXml = new XmlDocument();
                HttpWebRequest oRequest = CreateListRequest(clientContext, folderUri);
                using(Stream responseStream = oRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()) {
                    Debug.Assert(responseStream != null);
                    using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(responseStream)) {
                        responseXml.Load(reader);
                    }
                }

                // Process the response xml document
                foreach(XmlElement element in responseXml.GetDAVResponses()) {
                    if(filesOnly && element.IsFolderResponse()) continue;
                    string href = element.GetResponseHref();
                    yield return href;
                }

            }

            #endregion
        }
    }
```

The above code should be usable as:

```
    // Files only
    foreach(string fileUrl in spList.RootFolder.ListRecursively()) {
        ...
    }

    // Files & Folders
    foreach(string pathUrl in spList.RootFolder.ListRecursively(false)) {
        ...
    }
```

If necessary, you can get the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File` & `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder` objects from the URLs. (`context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl` I think. If not, you'll have to look it up)

**Note**: Haven't actually tested this. Threw it together from the source code in a few of my previous projects, so sorry for any unused/unnecessary code that was left in.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to add an `OrderBy` clause to your CAML query, to order by `ID`. `ID` is a naturally indexed column in SP, so ordering by ID should help overcome the 5000 threshold. To be done maybe in conjonction with a `RowLimit` to avoid the timeout...

```
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy>
```

That would make:

```
query.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' /><Value Type='ContentTypeId'>0x0120</Value></BeginsWith></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>" + FileFoldeBatchSize + "</RowLimit></View>";
```

**Update**
As per [this MSDN blog thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/53f69223-16bb-46bc-b047-dc0e8d634dd9/retrieving-all-list-items-via-api?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious), we may need the `Override='TRUE'` attribute on the `OrderBy`clause + `Scope='Recursive'` on the `View`. i.e.:

```
query.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' /><Value Type='ContentTypeId'>0x0120</Value></BeginsWith></Where><OrderBy Override='TRUE'><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>" + FileFoldeBatchSize + "</RowLimit></View>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, still the same. Just times out, however I have read that I could put an index on the content type. Of course this would have to be done at the start when the list is below the threshold limit

Comment: We're maybe missing the `Override` attribute on the `OrderBy` clause + `Scope=`'Recursive'`, as stated in https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/53f69223-16bb-46bc-b047-dc0e8d634dd9/retrieving-all-list-items-via-api?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: Just updated my project and get the following exception Additional information: The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.

Comment: Just being curious: what if you remove the `Where` clause?

Comment: It works without the Where clause, I can download everything in batches without any problems, its just I wanted to know if you could query lists of this size. When I introduce the Where clause, this is when it times out.

Comment: @Webfort You might only be able to query by indexed columns.  Of course you cannot create an indexed column once the list/library has exceeded 5000 items...

Comment: Just trying that now, I've deleted all the files, created an index on the contenttype and then added then restored the files. Will update with the results